# What is the use of Watched Tags in Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, tags, tag-watching

What is the use of "Watched Tags" in Stack Overflow? What are they meant for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know, you get an overview of the watched tag + the possibility to quickfilter for your tag in the [questions overview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions).

Comment: It's on the right hand side of the page. I think previously it was on the left.

Comment: You can filter questions that are not answered and has your watched tag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tab=Unanswered&tagMode=Watched